# how to change an existing postgresql 12 master to slave?

Tags: postgresql, failover, master-slave

i have setup a master-slave postgresql 12 servers with pgpool, while master is down, the slave is become master, then i need to manually change the original master slave.  my thought is ：
1. execute pg_rewind in the original master
2. touch a "standby.singal" file
3. execute pg_ctl start

1 and were done, but fail at 3 with error:

```
2020-04-28 20:33:09.071 CST [248626] FATAL:  highest timeline 2 of the primary is behind recovery timeline 3
cp: cannot stat ‘/data/pgdata/12/archive/00000004.history’: No such file or directory
```

what's wrong ? and What's the right procedure to change an existing postgresql 12 master to slave?

Comment: You'd have to describe the setup in more detail. What is the recovery configuration, what was the timeline before failover, how exactly did you fail over?

Answer (score 0):

following this fixed my problem
https://www.highgo.ca/2019/11/07/replication-failover-with-pg_rewind-in-pg12/